# Name for nth boundary = 0 rather than 2nd boundary = 0?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was reading up on algebraic topology ([MIT OCW](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-905-algebraic-topology-i-fall-2016/resources/mit18_905f16_lec1/)), and noticed the boundary operator was a little arbitrary. Informally, to take the boundary you index an n-simplex and introduce a phase of $(-1)^i$ when removing the $i$th index. You reindex when taking the second boundary, so the two ways of removing indices $i, j$ result in phases of $$(-1)^{i+j} + (-1)^{i+j-1}$$
which cancels out. Hence, "the boundary of a boundary is zero". A cycle is then defined as a structure with zero boundary, and the homologies are the nontrivial cycles (everything but boundaries).

However, the phase $-1$ seems arbitrary. What if you wanted it to be zero exactly on the $n$th boundary, rather than the second? Let the phase be $x^{-1}$. There are $n!$ ways to delete $n$ indices, which gives phases
$$(x^{0}+x^{1}+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-1})(x^{0}+x^{1}+\cdots+x^{n-2})\cdots(x^0+x^1)(x^0)$$
which we want to equal zero. Note that $x=1$ never works, so we need
$$(x^{n}-1)(x^{n-1}-1)\cdots(x^{1}-1)=0,$$
so $x$ is a product of $i$th roots of unity ($i\le n$). The only $n$ that work are the prime powers.

Is there a name for this generalization of homologies?

Comment: What are you proposing as the analogue of $\ker \partial/\operatorname{im} \partial$? Part of the motivation for $\partial^2 = 0$ is arguably that it "holds" on the level of manifolds, i.e. if $M$ is an $n$-manifold with boundary, $\partial M$ is an $(n-1)$-manifold with empty boundary.

Comment: $\ker \partial = \{X: \partial^n X = 0\}$, and $\mathrm{im}\ \partial = \partial S_{n+1}$

Comment: I've never seen anything like this worked out; one first step towards seeing if it is interesting would be to compute a few basic examples, e.g. $S^1, T^2, S^2$.

Comment: @TabesBridges isn't the reason $\partial^2 = 0$ for $n$-manifolds because of the phase $-1$? You can build the manifold by a limit of simplices.

Comment: The phase thing you are talking about on the level of simplices ensures that when you take the boundary of two simplices that share a face, the boundary of the sum doesn't include that face. Each copy of the face coming from a simplex cancels in the sum.

Comment: It actually doesn't depend on the phase.

For a more concrete example of taking the boundary, imagine the 3-simplex ABCD and one of its faces BCD. A phase of +1 corresponds to pointing towards A, while a phase of -1 points in the opposite direction. If another simplex BCDE, existed, then E would be the reflection of A across BCD, so the signs would reverse. No matter what the phase is, face BCD will cancel out.

Comment: Perhaps if you learn the geometry behind the boundary formula --- rather than just staring at the formula itself --- you will learn that it is not arbitrary at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can view a standard chain complex (in which $\partial \circ \partial = 0$) of $R$-modules as graded module over $R[\partial]/(\partial^2)$. Then the homology is measuring how far this graded module is from being free: the homology is zero if and only if the module is free.

You can instead consider modules over $R[x]/(x^n)$ for any $n$, and define a version of homology: fix $i<n$ and consider $\ker (x^i) / \mathrm{im} (x^{n-i})$. These modules will correspond to the variant of a chain complex in which $\partial^n = 0$, and this homology will be zero for an $R[x]/(x^n)$-module (maybe with some extra assumptions, like positively graded) if and only if the module is free. This is used by [Moore and Peterson](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/moore-peterson.pdf) and by [Miller and Wilkerson](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ehrm/papers/miller-wilkerson-vanishing-lines.pdf), to name two examples. Miller and Wilkerson claim that this type of homology theory was first studied by Mayer in "[A New Homology Theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1968874)" (although they misspelled Mayer's name), and Spanier wrote a paper about it called "[The Mayer homology theory](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-02/S0002-9904-1949-09179-6/S0002-9904-1949-09179-6.pdf)." Spanier's paper considers the relationship between Mayer homology and ordinary homology. (Mayer homology is not quite the same as what you're talking about: it requires the coefficient group to be an abelian group in which every element has order $p$, and it just omits the signs completely from the usual boundary map. As a result, the boundary map has order $p$.)

I don't think the term "Mayer homology" is in common use, but at least it has a pedigree, so maybe it's as good a name as any.